# Define a function inside loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numerical-methods

```
def lin_min(alpha):#1
    return 1       #2
xk = init_path
for i in range(0, 50):
    sk = -dobj(xk)
    def lin_min(alpha):
        return obj(xk + alpha*sk)
    opt = sopt.golden(lin_min)
    xk = xk + opt * sk
```

I'm trying to define a function inside the loop. However, it does not work until I add the first two lines at the top. They have nothing to do with my function but the code works this time. Why is that?

Comment: Why do you want to define the function inside the loop? There are scenarios where that makes sense but this doesn't seem like one of them. Just make the function accept all the values as parameters: `def lin_min(alpha, xk, sk): return obj(xk + alpha*sk)`

Comment: That's odd. But it's difficult to answer your question without knowing more about  `dobj`, `obj` and `sopt.golden`. Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces this problem.

Comment: @tripleee `lin_min` is being passed to `sopt.golden`, and unless `sopt.golden` can be supplied with a parameter list for the callback, the parameters need to be baked in.

Comment: If I take out all your external functions and do something like `opt = sorted([1, 2, 3], key=lin_min)` it works without the initial `def` for me. I second the request for a proper [mcve].

Comment: I don't have the complete code,  sorry about that. spot.golden is python script.optimize.golden.  obj is the objective function and dobj is to find the gradient. This code is used for optimization. I just find the way I declare the function is strange and confusing and not sure whether there is a better way to do that.